# Programmatically load usercontrol to a div in masterpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

There are different user controls to be included in the master page dynamically.

Only some of the pages inheriting the master page will be required to display some of the user controls. I need to know what are the best options for displaying these user controls. Can we decide which user control is to be loaded and do it programmatically through code? Or is there a way in javascript or jquery to do this?

I wanted to know how to load the user control programatically to a div in master page from a content page.

Comment: A little bit of sample code would be great so people can see what you exactly want to accomplish and what you've tried so far :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load UserControls dynamically by using the [LoadControl method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.templatecontrol.loadcontrol.aspx) available on all TemplateControl based classes (such as Page, UserControl and MasterPage). See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) for an expanded explanation.

```
var userControl = (TheTypeOfMyUserControl)LoadControl("~/MyUserControl.ascx");
var div = TheNameOfMyRunAtServerDiv;
div.Controls.Add(userControl);
```

**Edit:** The above is required to be placed in the MasterPage. If you want to invoke it from a content page you can create a public method on the MasterPage that the page can call (taking the user control path as a parameter).

Comment: To get the "TheNameOfMyRunAtServerDiv" from the masterpage he will either need to add <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MastPageName.master" %> to his child page or use ((MasterPageName)This.Master).TheNameOfMyRunAtServerDiv as his page wont have direct access to the masterpage's controls otherwise

Comment: True. A method can be created in the MasterPage for loading the UserControl and then it can be invoked from the pages with the user control path as a parameter. It's hard to tell a "best" way without knowing a concrete scenario.

Answer (score 1):

following code will work for you,

```
UserControl uc = (UserControl)LoadControl("controlPath");
div.Controls.Add(uc);
```

reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c0az2h86(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: That will not work if the user control has a template (ascx), which is one of the main points of having a user control. The control has to be loaded using the LoadControl method.